# powershell.exe start-process -About "\" when using the Verb option

Tags: powershell, cmd, elevated-privileges, start-process

Thank you for your help.
I use Powershell in the Windows 10 command prompt and try to execute commands with administrative rights.
When I try the following three, a, b and c, I cannot start with "RunAs" as I think.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

(a) It can be executed successfully. The arguments are also passed correctly.
`powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '\"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb Open`

(b) Does not start after UAC confirmation.
`powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '\"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb RunAs`

(c) It is possible to invoke it, but the "B C" argument is not reflected in the "double quotes" argument, and "B C" is recognized separately.
`powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '"a" "B C" "d"' -Verb RunAs`

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
REM From cmd.exe (Command Prompt) / a batch file:
powershell.exe -c Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs ('/k {0} \"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -f ((Convert-Path 'TestEnv.cmd') -replace ' ', '^^ '))
```

- Replace `/k` with `/c` to make the new window close automatically when the batch file exits.
- The *working directory* for the batch file is `C:\Windows\System32`.

If you also want to ensure that the batch file executes *in the caller's current directory*:

```
REM From cmd.exe (Command Prompt) / a batch file:
powershell.exe -c Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs ('/k cd \"{0}\" ^&^& {1} \"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -f $PWD.ProviderPath, ((Convert-Path 'TestEnv.cmd') -replace ' ', '^^ '))
```

Read on for an explanation.

---

The **main problem** is:

- **When you pass a batch-file path *directly* - as the executable - to `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, there seems to be a problem with passing an argument list that contains double quotes (`"`)** - I don't know the reason, but the problem occurs in a layer *below* PowerShell, either in the underlying [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) .NET API or possibly even in the underlying [`ShellExecuteExe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) WinAPI function.
- (If you either need *no* arguments or none of them require `"`, you *can* pass the batch-file path directly as the executable; by default, because the underlying executable is `cmd.exe`, which is located in `C:\Windows\System32`, `C:\Windows\System32` becomes the working directory, which you can override with `-WorkingDirectory`, but note that you must then refer to the batch file with a (possibly relative) *path*, if it is located elsewhere.)

**Workaround**:

- Instead of using the batch-file path *directly* as the executable to launch, use `cmd.exe` as the executable, and pass the batch-file path and all its arguments as arguments to the `/c` option (or `/k`, if you want to keep the new window open).
- Unfortunately, with `-Verb Runas`, `cmd.exe` *invariably* uses `C:\Windows\System32` as the new process' working directory - passing a startup directory with the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter is then ignored.

  - The same applies to `powershell.exe`, but, curiously, *not* to `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell [Core] v6+) and *.NET-based* executables, which (a) *preserve the caller's working directory* by default and (b) do honor a `-WorkingDirectory` argument.
- Therefore, if your `TestEnv.cmd` batch file is located in the *current* directory - as opposed to a directory listed in the `PATH` environment variable (`$env:PATH`) - you must pass the batch file's *full path* to `cmd.exe`, which you can determine with [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path).

  - Note: If you batch file *is* in the `PATH`, so to speak, this step isn't necessary.
  - Unfortunately, *another* workaround is then needed, in case the batch file's full path contains *spaces*: Because `"..."`-enclosing the batch-file path inexplicably *fails*, the individual spaces must be `^`-escaped instead.

**From *inside PowerShell*** this means your command must look like this (note that I'm using `/k` to keep the new window open, for diagnostic purposes; use `/c` to auto-close the window when the batch file exits):

```bsh
# From inside PowerShell:
Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs (
  '/k {0} "a" "B C" "d"' -f ((Convert-Path 'TestEnv.cmd') -replace ' ', '^ ')
)
```

**Caveat**: Since `cmd.exe` is being invoked, `C:\Windows\System32` is the working directory.
If you also want to **ensure that the batch file executes *in the caller's current directory***, you must prepend a `cd` command:

```bsh
# From inside PowerShell:
Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs (
  '/k cd "{0}" && {1} "a" "B C" "d"' -f $PWD.ProviderPath, ((Convert-Path 'TestEnv.cmd') -replace ' ', '^ ')
)
```

---

**Calling this *from `cmd.exe`* (Command Prompt) / a batch file**, via [*Windows PowerShell*'s CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PowerShell.exe), `powershell.exe` (note that in *PowerShell [Core] v6+* it is now [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh)), adds additional complexity:

- The `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"` so that PowerShell recognizes as them as part of the command to execute rather than as syntactic quoting around the CLI arguments.
- `^` must be escaped as `^^` and, in the second command below, `&` as `^&` to prevent `cmd.exe` from interpreting these characters (up front).

```
REM From cmd.exe (Command Prompt) / a batch file:
powershell.exe -c Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs ('/k {0} \"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -f ((Convert-Path 'TestEnv.cmd') -replace ' ', '^^ '))
```

If you also want to ensure that the batch file executes *in the caller's current directory*:

```
REM From cmd.exe (Command Prompt) / a batch file:
powershell.exe -c Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs ('/k cd \"{0}\" ^&^& {1} \"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -f $PWD.ProviderPath, ((Convert-Path 'TestEnv.cmd') -replace ' ', '^^ '))
```

Comment: Good one. I gave it a shot and I still don't understand why the behaviour changes with RunAs (talking about the quotes here), it's like it's suddenly impossible to have spaces in the argument list for no obvious reason. Good job on the workaround.

Comment: Thanks, @PMental. Yes, the behavior definitely sounds buggy.

Comment: Sounds buggy to me too. I raised an issue https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14099

Comment: I even looked at the source code for Start-Process and still can't see the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  
I knew it was a bug.  
I knew how to relay another method, such as CMD.  
I just didn't know about it and was wondering if I could get around it by using Powershell's options and escape sequences.  
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinBrown, I've added information that the bug comes from a layer _below_ PowerShell to the answer, so we can clean up our comments here.

Comment: My Issue got closed (quite reasonably) as a duplicate of this: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576

Comment: @MartinBrown: That's a separate issue that occurs irrespective of `-Verb RunAs`. The bug at hand is: using a _single_ `-ArgumentList` string with _embedded_ quoting generally works, but with `-Verb RunAs` it doesn't. I have not tried to report it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, mklement0, everyone.
The answer was approved.
In addition to Powershell, the ShellExecute function of WSH seems to have the same problem.
I have been running Powershell with administrative privileges from the ShellExecute function to solve this problem in JSCRIPT. I then run the desired commands and arguments in Powershell to get around the problem.
The substitution method you showed me, mklement0, was very informative. Thank you very much.